# Format Specifier of byte in Java

Tags: java, byte, specifier

What's the format specifier of byte in Java?

For example,

```
%d=int

%s=short

%f=float
```

Comment: [The documentation lists it out.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)  It's attached to the `Formatter` class.

Comment: %d=int, %d=short, %d=long, %d=byte, %d=BigInteger... Java has RTTI.

Comment: To be explicit, `%s` is for string not for `short`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `%d` for decimal output (works for all integer types, not just `int`), but this will print the signed value (such as `-100`), which can be unexpected for a byte.

You can also use `%x` for hexadecimal.